# Excel MATCH with match_type = -1 failing

Tags: excel

I'm struggling with the `MATCH()` function in Excel when using a match_type of `-1` (greater than).

I have a table as follows:

```
      -A-     -B-
-1-   83      0
-2-   83      1950
-3-   88      2440
-4-   93      2440
-5-   93      0
-6-
-7-   85.6
```

I want to find the gradient at any point on the envelope that these points create, so I want to find the corresponding column -B- value for an intermediate column -A- value.

Step 1 in my process is to find the values *below* my query value. I do this with:

`=MATCH(A7,A1:A5,1)` (A7 contains my lookup value)

This works fine, and I then use the result of the `MATCH()` function with `INDEX()` to lookup the corresponding -B- column value.

Step 2 in my process is to find the values *above* my query value. For this I have:

`=MATCH(A7,A1:A5,-1)` (A7 contains my lookup value)

However this does not work. I get an `=N/A` error in the formula cell.

Showing calculation steps doesn't help as all of the values and ranges are being picked up correctly from what I can see....

Comment: Why two columns? MATCH only works on 1 column. Why -1? -1 is intended to be used on data sorted descending?

Comment: I wonder if match is assuming the data in column a is alphanumeric. Hence the -1 for smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value may be failing. What happens if you set the range (A1:A5) to numeric (Format Cells>Numeric). - and A7 too?

Comment: @Jeeped Two columns because ultimately I am calculating a gradient of a line and then an intermediate value - the match is only operating on the first column, then index does the lookup. I need to calculate the corresponding B value for an A value of 85.6 (assuming a linear gradient between each of the points on the lines described by the table above). I understood from the Excel docs that a match_type of 1 get the nearest value less than the first argument , and -1 gets the nearest value greater than the first argument.

Comment: =MATCH(40,B2:B5,-1) Returns an error because the values in the range B2:B5 are **not in descending order**.

Comment: @JGFMK Setting column A to numeric makes no difference I'm afraid. (It was set to general)

Comment: @Jeeped So how would I do the two types of match on the same data set? I need to find the nearest values that are greater than AND less than my target value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
'<= A7
=INDEX(B1:B5, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(1:5)/(A1:A5<=A7), 1))
'>= A7
=INDEX(B1:B5, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(1:5)/(A1:A5>=A7), 1))
```

To cope with blank rows in the data set try,

```
'<= A7
=INDEX(B1:B5, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(1:5)/((A1:A5<=A7)*(A1:A5<>"")), 1))
'>= A7
=INDEX(B1:B5, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(1:5)/((A1:A5>=A7)*(A1:A5<>"")), 1))
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. Could you explain what the ROW(1:5) does though - I'm now adapting this to my actual spreadsheet and want o make sure I understand exactly what these formulae are doing.

Comment: It's the *position within* B1:B5, not the row number on the worksheet. If B1:B5 was B2:B20, it would be ROW(1:19).

Comment: I thought that might be the case.. I get zero returned in my actual spreadsheet having changes the row() function to match the real size. It seems that the problem is that my table *can* contain blank rows at the end... is there an easy way to cope with that?

Comment: a) yes there is b) that seems more like a new question than something that can be addressed in comments c) that new condition invalidates my current response,

Comment: Did you try changing `(A1:A5<=A7)` to `((A1:A5<=A7)*(A1:A5<>""))` ?

Comment: Neat little tweak! That works a charm. Have added to your answer and accepted.

Comment: I had originally been thinking about changing the ranges to something more llike `B1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1e99, B:B))` which was why I proposed a new question but the less-invasive `(A1:A5<>"")` should work just as well.